# Why I have to wait some time before Ctrl+Z works again when using BufferedReader()!

Tags: java, eclipse, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter, bufferedinputstream

I have the following code:

```
  import java.io.*;

public class BufferedWriteToFile {
//Read every line from br, write everything into bw
public static void br2bw(BufferedReader br, BufferedWriter bw) throws IOException {
    String z;       //Line
    while ((z = br.readLine()) != null) { //Read
                                            //Stream check
        bw.write(z);                        //writing
        bw.newLine();                       //next line
    }
    br.close();
    bw.close();
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    try {
        File datei = new File(args[0]);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(datei));
        System.out.println("Type some text please");
        System.out.println("(You can stop with Ctrl+Z \n");
        br2bw(in, out); //read from in, write into out
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(datei));
        out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
        System.out.println("\nIn " +args[0] + "saved Text:");
        br2bw(in, out); //read from in, write out
    }catch (IOException e) {

      }
  }
```

}

Tryint out my code in Eclipse I experienced that it does not always work the same way:
    1, some times it works okay, it saved the typed text into the file
    2, some other times if I press Ctrl+Z nothing happens at all
    3, sometimes if I wait a little ant after some time I press it again it works
    4, if Ctrl+Z works but I have only yped one line it just saves an empty file

Can you please explain me why do the following scenarios happen and how can I avoid them?

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: On most *nix systems, Ctrl-Z is "suspend process". Why are you telling your user to use it? Also: you need to add something to your question about what terminal you're using, as the answer most likely lies there.

Comment: I am using eclipse

Comment: Ctrl+Z is EOF on Windows.